# Social login error : Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am use Laravel socialite for facebook login

I've set app\config and app\service

I've ran the commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear:config
```

The project runs successfully but on server it's showing error

> Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found

This is URL: http://courtyardconversation.com

What could cause this error?

Comment: Did you run `composer install` in your server?

Comment: Sir I am use laravel socialite and make login with facebook and upload only web. php,  logincontroller,  home. blade. php, config\app.php and config\service.php

Comment: Dear sir how run composer install on server

Comment: When I am create a laravel project then download and install composer on local server.

Comment: Are you familiar with console shell ? What OS is your server running?

Comment: This is because you haven't install the package in your server. Are you using a shared hosting and con't have shell access?

If you have shell access then run composer install, else upload your vendor folder to your server again.

My guess is you used the socialite package after you have uploaded the project once in the server and latter only uploaded the controllers and views

Comment: @Saurav
dear sir,
your are Right. thanks

Comment: When I upload to the Larval Project  on server, then the server local path is raised like c:/xampp/htdocs  please tell me. thanks in advance